# If you want to test a step-up transformer, must the load resistor equal the source impedance?

Tags: transformer, measurement

Ideally, do you want to add R1 to balance out the impedance so you get an accurate reading?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk2mxk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**I'm trying to find out the turn ratio of the transformer by using a signal generator and 5V. So a 1:3 ratio should produce 15V, and 1:5 should be 25V.**

This is not the case at 130kHz without R1, which means it's probably self-resonant or something, and I'm trying to find out why I get 5V in and 100V out on my oscilloscope.

Comment: If L2 is 25mH and L1 is 0.1mH, the turns ratio is 15.8 to 1. If those aren't the values please justify or correct your error (if you "wanna").

Comment: As soon as you decide to read the part about resonance affecting the coupling I'll let you know why your math is wrong. Only if you "wanna".

Comment: Not really bothered but if you think you can ask questions clouded in riddles and text-talk then please carry on.

Comment: You're feeble if you constitute a one word difference as "clouded in riddles and text-talk". Or maybe just aggressive, I don't particularly care.

Comment: Is R1 really 100 Ohms?  Or is that just because you didn't edit the default value when entering the schematic?

Comment: I selected R1 so that it matched the sum of the output impedance and the coaxial impedance. Which is 50 + 50, so yeah definitely 100R, I didn't misrepresent it.

Comment: Okay - you are overloading your transformer. The impedance ratio is the square of the turns ratio. With a turns ratio of about 15.8, you should be loading the transformer secondary with a resistor value of 50 * 250 or about 1250 Ohms. Why don't you try that resistor value for R1 and see what happens?

Comment: I don't think I am, to be honest. The voltage is misrepresented even after adding 100, 1000, 2000~, 5000 ohms. It was the scope and it's 1M/10M impedance that misrepresented the voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but inductance is directly related to the square of the number of turns in the coil.

You mention that the primary is 100 uH and the secondary is 25 mH.  For me, the turns ratio should be SquareRoot (25mH / 100uH) = SquareRoot 250 which is about 15.8

I'm not sure why you say the math is wrong.

Comment: Here's why the math is wrong;

When R1 is not added, the output impedance is 50R + 50R on the generator apparatus. The voltage divider it creates when you associate it with X(L) means that you have to factor in the frequency. At 130kHz fres you know that (1/(2pi*130000*0.025))) is X(L), which is added to the opposite side of the circuit, and becomes the other part of the impedance, meaning there's a progressively larger error as you change frequencies away from X(L) = R.

Aside from that, the voltage divider results V(gain) + V(L) = ~R/X(L), instead of V(L).

You will always have a f:X(L) gain

Comment: But yeah, I solved the actual question itself, "If you want to test a step-up transformer, must the load resistor equal the source impedance?". You have to make sure that you are not probing with a scope that is unmatched, i.e. High-Z versus 50R. Otherwise you incur R:X(L) gain, and instead of "a 1:3 ratio should produce 15V", you get, "I get 5V in and 100V out on my oscilloscope".

Comment: Also, you get 5.481 as the turn ratio, with error accounted for. That's why the funny guy above who insisted on being so abrasive was wrong. There are 37 turns on my secondary, 205 on my primary by calculation. There is definitely not 584 turns on it, just from counting by eye and weight, but as you can see there's an error of 2.85~ when you don't factor in the impedance.